# Google API's Explorer doesn't work

Tags: google-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to use Google API's explorer to get a better sense of how to structure my requests and such. However, the explorer doesn't seem to work for me.

Example: I go [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/books/v1/books.volumes.list) and enter Moby Dick in the query input box, toggle Authorize Requests using OAuth 2.0, then click Execute. It shows a loading animation, and says Executing, then the request finishes and it displays something like `books.volumes.list executed moments ago time to execute: 437 ms` - and that's it.

There's tons of white space below that, where I assume the response should be, but it's blank.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Works for me - I've just followed your link, typed "moby dick" into the query, hit Execute, and got a load of data in the response. What browser are you using? Can you go into a developer console to trace the requests/responses?

Comment: Chrome on Mac. How would I find the trace?

Comment: @JonSkeet Just tried it in Incognito and it worked so I'm going to try clearing cache/cookies and trying again

Comment: Open up the developer console (F12 on a Windows box... don't know about Mac) and look in the Network tab. Once the console is open, try the request again (ideally with a different query).

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok there are 4 requests (2 to Google Analytics, 1 for the loading GIF, and one for the actual get request). Status is 200 (OK).

Comment: And does it include the data in the response? That's the important bit.